# Boot related tags, should we synonymize them all?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I've seen that more often that most, [multi-boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/multi-boot), [triple-boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/triple-boot), [dual-boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dual-boot) are usually about the [boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/boot) process. Shouldn't we synonymize them all?

Comment: And on a side note, as I'm merging I've noticed that `multi-boot` doesn't exist, and `multiboot` is already a synonym of `dual-boot`.

Comment: @Oli My vote is in favour of multi-boot or multiboot. We should synonymize all of them to multiboot or multi-boot. That will help the people trying to answer all of the multiple OS questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not into [boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/boot) but maybe one tag to describe all multiple-boot scenarios.

I think [dual-boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dual-boot) covers it. What do you reckon?

Comment: Seems legit, since boot could be single boot system.